Как определить начальный fqdn (initial URL)?
Вопрос про связку веб-браузер + прокси. Можно ли в самом прокси-сервере как-то определить запрос, который инициировал остальные?
Например, пользователем был запрошен сайт habr.com, далее в процессе  загрузки браузер запросил habrastorage, googleapis, gstatic, и тд.
Проблема осложняется еще тем, что из других вкладок также идут запросы с уже открытых сайтов.
Парсинг исходного текста сайта вылавливает только малую часть ссылок. Пока единственный полностью автономный вариант - это использование webdriver для отслеживания всех связанных запросов, но это довольно ресурсоемко.
